# Is there a way to compute a roughness value out of a roughness texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, pbr

I am just wondering if I can somehow find a way to estimate a single roughness value from a roughness texture for a specific material. I feel that the material might look better if I have found a way to estimate the roughness factor.

Comment: Open the roughness map in GIMP or Photoshop, resize the image to be 1px by 1px, with default resampling, see what the value of that pixel is.  That's the "average" roughness.